# Uploading pdf file from docx2pdf to database table in python

Tags: python, django, database, docx

I want to upload a generated pdf to my database table.
I am using `doxc2pdf` to convert a docx file to a pdf file in python:

```
convert("input.docx", "output.pdf")
```

So the output file that is generated is called "output.pdf" now i want to upload this to my "generated_report_file_upload" in my Report_File_Upload_Table DB table:

```
Report_File_Upload_Table.objects.create(generated_report_file_upload=output)
```

The problem is that i am getting an error saying that name `'output' is not defined`. full code of the function is below:

```
    doc = docx.Document()
    doc.add_heading("no text")
    doc.save('thisisdoc.docx')
    convert("thisisdoc.docx", "output.pdf") 
    Report_File_Upload_Table.objects.create(generated_report_file_upload=output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a false orientation of the `Report_File_Upload_Table.objects.create` kwargs. [Python kwargs are set by `key=value`.](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/args_and_kwargs.html)

To fix this you just need to set output as key with `generated_report_file_upload` as value i.e. :

```py
    Report_File_Upload_Table.objects.create(output=generated_report_file_upload)
```

What you've tried is to set the key `generated_report_file_upload` with the variable `output` as value that isn't defined.

Comment: Sorry i should have been more clear, my key is in fact `generated_report_file_upload` and my desired output is `output.pdf`. which is the pdf file that i made from converting it from a docx file. i am doing some research here and maybe have to use io.bytes but i am unsure..?